# Pygame creating surfaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame, time, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
from time import gmtime, strftime

pygame.init()

w = 640
h = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h),RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = y = 100

def starting():
    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
    text = basicfont.render('Starting...', True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255))
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    screen.blit(text, textrect)

def taskbar():
    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
    taskbarrect = pygame.Rect((0, int(h-40)), (int(w), int(h)))
    text = basicfont.render(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = basicfont.render(strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))
    taskbarrect.blit(text, (w - 100, h - 37))
    taskbarrect.blit(text2, (w - 100, h - 17))
    pygame.display.update()

starting()
screen.fill((255,255,255))

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()  
        elif event.type==VIDEORESIZE:
            w = event.dict['size'][0]
            h = event.dict['size'][1]
            screen=pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'],RESIZABLE)
    taskbar()
```

Because I want to make my code run faster, I want to create surfaces and blit rects on top of them, so that I can do `pygame.display.update(taskbarrect)` and speed up my code. However, I don't know how to create multiple surfaces. I have tried `taskbarrect=(xcoordinate, ycoordinate, width, length)` then blitting an image or text or whatever, but trying it says `tuple object has no attribute blit`. Trying the method in the code (suggested by @elegent) gives `'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'blit'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, it´s hard to help you when you don´t provide us some code where the error actually happens. ;)

Comment: You don´t need to crate a new Surface; just blit the text onto the main screen (see my updated answer).

Comment: @elegent would there be much of a difference? ie how much will the fps diminish?

Answer (score 11):

Pygame uses *[surfaces](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)* to represent any form of image. This could be either

- your main screen Surface, which is returned by the [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) function

  ```
  myDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
  ```
- or created object of the `pygame.Surface` class:

  ```
  #create a new Surface
  myNewSurface = Surface((500, 300))

  #change its background color
  myNewSurface.fill((55,155,255))

  #blit myNewSurface onto the main screen at the position (0, 0)
  myDisplay.blit(myNewSurface, (0, 0))

  #update the screen to display the changes
  display.update() #or  display.flip()
  ```

Pygame's [`display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) has a method that allows one to update only some portions of the screen by passing one object or a list of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects to it. Therefore, we could also call:

```
myUpdateRect= pygame.Rect((500, 300), (0, 0))
display.update(myUpdateRect)
```

Anyway, I recommend to using the [`pygame.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module to draw simple shapes like *rectangles*, *circles* and *polygons* onto a surface, because all of these functions return a rectangle representing the bounding area of changed pixels.

This enables you to pass this information to the `update()` function, so Pygame only updates the pixels of the just drawn shapes:

```
myDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))

myRect= pygame.Rect((100, 200), (50, 100))
pygame.display.update(pygame.draw.rect(myDisplay, (55, 155, 255), myRect))
```

Update:

```
def taskbar():
    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)

    text = basicfont.render(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = basicfont.render(strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))

    screen.fill((55, 155, 255))

    screen.blit(text, (w - 100, h - 37))
    screen.blit(text2, (w - 100, h - 17))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "desktop/opsys.py", line 45, in <module>
    taskbar()
  File "desktop/opsys.py", line 27, in taskbar
    taskbarrect = pygame.Surface((0, int(h-40)), (int(w), int(h)))
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: @YuBinLee: As I mentioned in my answer, the constructor of a the `pygame.Surface` class needs a tuple representing the size (i.e. the resolution) of the surface. You want to create a `pygame.Rect` object: `taskbarrect = pygame.` **`Rect`** `((0, int(h-40)), (int(w), int(h)))`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chef\Desktop\opsys.py", line 45, in <module>
    taskbar()
  File "C:\Users\chef\Desktop\opsys.py", line 30, in taskbar
    taskbarrect.blit(text, (w - 100, h - 37))
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'blit'