# Convert rectangle to surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, surface, rect, blit

In my code it keeps giving me the error:

> `pygame.surface.Surface.blit(a, (x1, y1))`
>
> TypeError: descriptor 'blit' requires a 'pygame.Surface' object but received a 'pygame.Rect'.

Help!

This is my code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode()

display_width = 1366
display_height = 768

white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

global x1
global y1
global x2
global y2

x1 = 683
y1 = 384
x2 = 0
y2 = 500


def game():
    y1 = 384
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    a = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (x1,y1,250,250), 0)
    b = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, (x2,y2,100,100), 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    gameStart = True
    while gameStart == True:
        while True:               
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        print('Forward')
                        y1 = y1 + 1
                        a = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (x1,y1,250,250), 0)
                        pygame.surface.Surface.blit(a, (x1, y1))
                        pygame.display.update()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        print('Backward')
                        y1 = y1 - 1
                        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (x1,y1,250,250), 0)
                        pygame.display.update()










game()
```

BTW: the section for if the s key pressed I have left the same until I get the if w key pressed section working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supposedly you can use `update` and pass it `Rect`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873817/pygame-creating-surfaces

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve. Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use create a new pygame.Surface object with the rects dimensions

```
surf = pygame.Surface((a.w, a.h))
screen.blit(surf)
```