# Trying to draw a pygame sprite in a class but error comes

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to draw a sprite in pygame inside a class however I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

# Initiate Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set The Screen Size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

# Set The Window Title & Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Pacman")



# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.draw = screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200)
    


# Background Image

backImg_1 = pygame.image.load("maze.png").convert()
backImg = pygame.transform.scale(backImg_1, (800, 600))

# Game Loop
running = True

while running:
    # Player
    Player = Player()
    
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(backImg, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

Here is the error message I get when I try to run this code:

```
  File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 34, in <module>
    Player = Player()
  File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

The error message says that there is no `get_rect` method in pygame, however in pygame there is a `get_rect` method.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call the `Surface.convert()` function at

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert
```

to be

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert()
```

See the documentation for [`Surface.convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert).

---

For the new error *(provided by the OP in the comments)*,

```
File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 34, in <module>
     Player = Player()   File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 20, in __init__
     self.draw = screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200) 
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect
```

Simply replace

```
screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200)
```

with

```
color = 255, 0, 0
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color 200, 200, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)
```

Comment: I tried that but I now get a new error : `File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 34, in <module>
    Player = Player()
  File "/Users/nagz/Pacman/Pacman.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.draw = screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect
`

Comment: try to read the error message it informs you very clear, that your method call in line 20 expect a class Object called ```pygame.Surface``` but you used a ```pygame.Rect```. I am not completly into pygame but I think you should be able to turn a rect into a surface without a problem.
Here a question in relation to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373036/convert-rectangle-to-surface-in-pygame

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame

# Initiate Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set The Screen Size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

# Set The Window Title & Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Pacman")



# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.draw = screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200)
    


# Background Image

backImg_1 = pygame.image.load("maze.png").convert()
backImg = pygame.transform.scale(backImg_1, (800, 600))

# Game Loop
running = True

while running:
    # Player
    Player = Player()
    
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(backImg, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `()` after `convert`, change it to:

`self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert()`

and change:

`self.draw = screen.blit(self.rect, 200, 200)`

to

`self.draw = lambda: screen.blit(self.image, (200, 200))`

this way, you can just call `self.draw()`, whenever you wanna draw the sprite.

Here’s the code:

```
import pygame

# Initiate Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set The Screen Size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

# Set The Window Title & Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Pacman")



# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Pacman_Player.tiff").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.draw = lambda: screen.blit(self.image, (200,200))
    


# Background Image

backImg_1 = pygame.image.load("maze.png").convert()
backImg = pygame.transform.scale(backImg_1, (800, 600))

# Game Loop
running = True

while running:
    # Player
    Player = Player()
    
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(backImg, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```